# Left multiplication Fréchet Differentiable

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, continuity, matrix-inverse

Let $L^2$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $\{e_i(t)\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a basis for it.  Moreover let $\phi(T,z)$ and $\psi(T,z)$ be 1-parameter families (in z) in $L^2$, with basis expansions
$$
\phi(T,z) = \sum_i c_i(z)e_i(T), \, \psi(T,z) = \sum_i \tilde{c}_i(z)e_i(T)
$$

Then is the operator define by
$$
A(z)^{+}c_i(z)=\tilde{c}_i(z)
$$
continuous in z, where $c_i^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse.  It seems so to me but I am not certain about how to prove this?

Comment: (comment, delete it after changes) It seems like the notations are not consistent. Where do $c_i(z)$ and $\tilde{c}_i(z)$ as functions of $z$ belong? $c_i^+$ seems to be missing in the lines above.